# Run methods after full setup

Tags: java

I have a custom API that I am working on that has to go through a variety of steps to authenticate and set itself up. That setup being oAuth, HTTP Request, and Websockets. I have the setup done fine and all that working, but what I am having trouble after.

When I implement and initialize my API in the java program the methods like `api.methodHandler.sendMessage("Registering Events");` are running before the API finishes setting itself up.

I have tried using wait, sleeps, etc.

```
api.setupAPI(clientid, clientSecret, cid, uid, null);

api.methodHandler.sendMessage("Registering Events");
api.eventManager.registerEvent(new EventHandler());
```

No errors, but the methods are just running before they should.

Comment: It would help to see what `setupAPI` is doing.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca setup is just a ```void``` that initializes all the classes. So just a bunch of ```MyClass myClass = new MyClass``` and then runs a ```void setup()``` which starts the auth process.


```JAVA
settingsManager = new SettingsManager(client_id, client_secret, channel_id, user_id, access_token);
        webSocketManager = new WebSocketManager(this);```

Comment: Any framework you're using?

Comment: "Starts the auth process" -- in another thread, perhaps? Also, how do you know it is not set up *yet*, as opposed to just not set up successfully? Does it work if you insert a `Thread.sleep` with a suitable delay before the first `sendMessage` call?

Comment: Well its using websockets, so if the auth is wrong it will return a text response which has to be translated to an object to grab the "authenticated" data. Also i could use Thread.sleep but the maximum amount of time an auth can take is 120 seconds. So I dont want to make it sleep for that long when it may only take 4 seconds to auth. @DavidConrad

Answer (score 0):

There is a good site that explains your options for solving this problem: [Running Setup Data on Startup in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring). But to give you few options: You can annotate your method

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
@Order(20)
public void runMyLogicAfterAppIsInitialized() {
   ...
}
```

The `@Order` annotation is not necessary but if you have several methods annotated with `@EventListener` you can control their execution order

Or a bit older way is to implement `ApplicationListener` interface

```
@Component
public class StartupApplicationListenerExample implements
  ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOG 
      = Logger.getLogger(StartupApplicationListenerExample.class);

    public static int counter;

    @Override public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        LOG.info("Increment counter");
        counter++;
    }
}
```